# Reducir costos en windows azure si tienes varios sitios

Tags: azure, azure-sql

Desarrolle un sistema para un cliente el cual cuando lo fui desarrollando fue pensado para el, ahorita tiene varias amistades que les gusto el programa, actualmente lo tenia en un hosting, el cual miro que se tiene problemas con los hosting porque no son muy estables, así que me fui por utilizar windows azure, el cual miro que es demasiado estable comparado con los hosting tradicionales, pero es demasiado costoso, la idea es que con los hosting yo se los rentaba a 500 pesos por mes, ahorita miro que con windows azure me gasto como 1300 pesos al mes, el cual rentarlo por 2000 pesos al mes se me hace algo costoso. Actualmente lo que hago para montar la aplicación utilizo

- App Service (1 nucleo 1.75GB RAM 10 GB de almacentamiento con precio
  mensual $1,076.94/MES)
- SQL Database 10 DTU 250 GB Almecenamiento ($290.06/MES)
- Storage 250 GB para las imagenes ($144.75/MES)

El cual da un total aproximado $1,511.75/MES

Si tengo 5 clientes estaría pagando $7558.75 esto se me hace bastante costoso por mes, y también se me hace costoso para mis clientes 2000 pesos por mes si es que quiero ganarme algo.

Mi pregunta es cual es la mejorar formar en windows azure para reducir estos costos al momento de crear varias instancias.

Saludos.

Comment: ¿Lograste solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0):

Es difícil indicarte con precisión dónde optimizar tus costos sin conocer cómo está hecha tu aplicación, pero es muy probable que estés subutilizando tus recursos:

- El lugar donde más deberías poder ahorrar en costos es con Azure App Service, el cual te permite correr múltiples Web Apps dentro del mismo App Service Plan, con lo cual podrías mantener 1 App Service Plan Standard S1 (el de 1 núcleo y 1,75 GB de RAM) y poner ahí las 5 Web Apps de tus 5 clientes (Scott Hanselman tiene 20 sitios corriendo en el mismo plan https://www.hanselman.com/blog/PennyPinchingInTheCloudRunningAndManagingLOTSOfWebAppsOnASingleAzureAppService.aspx).
- Otro posible lugar de ahorro es en la base de datos: nuevamente, dependiendo de cómo esté hecha tu aplicación, podrías compartir una sola base de datos entre varios clientes en vez de usar una base de datos por cada uno.

Comment: muchas gracias por la respuesta en el caso de la base de datos como la compartes con otras?